# Can't verify app on iPhone when I want to run my own app iOS9

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, verification

I created an app using Xcode and I want to run it on my iPhone instead of the simulators. The app has successfully installed in the phone, but when I click it it says "untrusted developer", xCode gives error "Process launch failed: security". So I went to Settings> General> Profile on my phone and I trusted the app, however the application is listed as "Not Verified" and when I click "verify app" nothing happens, and I still can't run the app.

Comment: What's the provisional file you used? Did u use free provisioning?

Comment: I'm not sure, when I first install it there were some issues that come up and I just click fix the issues. When I check my provisioning profile of my phone, it says iOS team: provisioning profile: com.example.myapp. I'm using xCode 7

Comment: edit: sorry yeah I am using free provisioning.

Answer (score 2):

There are some procedures you need to follow to install the build in iOS 9 using Free provisioning

1. Open the XCode->Preference->Accounts
2. Click the + button in the bottom left, add your apple id
3. Your apple id is now added. Click your apple ID, tap the 'View Details' in the right side detail.
4. Click the 'create' button near the iOS Develoment identity.
5. Then goto your project setting, search for code signing identity, change its value to 'iOS Development'
6. Run the app again, Verify/Trust if necessary

Comment: I've followed the steps but I still can't verify the app on my iPhone.

Comment: Still getting errors here, getting an empty timeline from this page: https://developer.apple.com/system-status/

Answer (score 2):

I've had this problem a few times. The issue seems to be on Apple's side - verifying apps requires a connection to their server, which was down earlier today. It should be up now (at the time of this posting). Looks like you just have to wait it out when this happens, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

I usually encounter this problem when using a web proxy that intercepts SSL connections using a custom certificate (fe Burp or company proxy).

When installing the app, the following happens (I think):

1. XCode builds & installs the application
2. iOS automatically tries to verify the app
3. iOS uses SSL pinning and therefore can't validate the app
4. When you press "validate app" now, the internal state is somewhat corrupted

So in my case, I had to take the following steps:

1. Connect directly to the internet without proxy
2. Install the application
3. Settings -> Profiles -> my profile -> Trust developer
4. The app is already automatically validated
5. Switch to the proxied network
6. Launch app

I do believe this is some kind of bug in iOS where the validation state is somewhat corrupted because of failed SSL pinning.